# Posting to Django Application

Tags: django, forms, post, string

I am using a form from my Apache/PHP Server and Django to handle all my posts/requests. How can I set it so that a field is not set it won't cause an error?

PHP Form:

```
<form action="http://www.mydomain.com:8003/login/" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="remember"><br>
<input type="submit" value="send" id="send">
</form>
```

Django:

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
 from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

 @csrf_exempt
 def index(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         post = request.POST
         email = post['email']
         pass = post['password']
         remember = post['remember']
         if remember:
             expire_v = 30
         else:
             expire_v = None
         response = HttpResponse(email)
         response.set_cookie('emailaddress', email, max_age=expire_v)
         response.set_cookie('password', pass, max_age=expire_v)
         return response
```

The problem is if remember isn't checked than it causes an error.

Comment: Okay, figured it out. When sending a field that I want to allow to be blank from outside Django it `needs to be request.POST.get('remember', None)` instead of `request.POST['remember']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an awful lot wrong with this code and without knowing the error: Try use defaults when you are fetching the parameters from the request

```
email = request.POST.get('email', False)
password = request.POST.get('pass', False) # pass is a keyword in python
remember = request.POST.get('remember', False)
if email and password:
    response = HttpResponse(email)
    if remember:
        response.set_cookie('emailaddress', email, max_age=30)
        response.set_cookie('password', pass, max_age=30)
    return response
 else:
     # do something to indicate a problem
```